# odoo 16 reconciliation translate not working

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-16

when adding

```
name = fields.Char(translate=True,)
company_name = fields.Char(translate=True)
display_name = fields.Char(translate=True)
```

to the `res.partner` then go to trying to open the reconciliation action
i am geting

```
TypeError: (this.m2o_value||"").trim is not a function. (In '(this.m2o_value||"").trim()', '(this.m2o_value||"").trim' is undefined)
```

is was working in odoo 14 but when i upgraded to 16 is gave me this error.

can you help me with the js part i don't really unstained the error

i tried removing translate=True on the name and company name and the reconciliation works

Comment: weird error, do you have an online example of this issue in order to debug it and point you into the right direction?. You could reach me to solve this if you really need it

Comment: @aekis.dev this for live database on odoo sh

Comment: if you need to see the issue we can set a online meeting @aekis.dev

Comment: sure, you could send me an email invite to the meet and see it online at odoo.sh

Comment: @aekis.dev thank you for you help i have send you a meeting link when ever you available just join in [Sorry for the delay, testing new ios all my notification working]

Comment: Let's make a call later today so we could see it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's me again

After been able to test and debug your issue locally I endup with this solution that you need to include in you module

```py
class AccountReconciliation(models.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = 'account.reconciliation.widget'

    @api.model
    def get_all_data_for_manual_reconciliation(self, partner_ids, account_ids):
        res = super(AccountReconciliation, self).get_all_data_for_manual_reconciliation(partner_ids, account_ids)
        for partner_data in res.get('customers', []):
            if isinstance(partner_data.get('partner_name'), dict):
                partner_data['partner_name'] = partner_data['partner_name'].get(self.env.context['lang'], 'en_US')
        return res
```

The reason it's that after you change `res.partner` `name` field to be `translate=True` and get that change applied into the database that will cause the field column to be of type JSONB so any select to that field using direct SQL will get a JSON Object which is what happens in `get_all_data_for_manual_reconciliation` of `account.reconciliation.widget` model so I manually check that and properly select the value related to the current user lang stored in the Enviroment Context

Hope that you could solve your issue with this change. I have tested and it's working on my localhost